# Duplicate value in one column with different categories in another column in Power Query

Tags: powerbi, conditional-statements, duplicates, powerquery

If you observe the below table, Each asset is having multiple SourceTypes and the status of each SourceType was mentioned in "Status" Column.

| Name | SourceType | Date | Status |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Asset 1 | Security | 27-03-2024 | Active |
| Asset 1 | Application | 24-03-2024 | In-Active |
| Asset 1 | System | 27-03-2024 | Active |
| Asset 2 | System | 27-03-2024 | Active |
| Asset 2 | Security | 21-02-2024 | In-Active |
| Asset 2 | Application | 15-06-2023 | In-Active |
| Asset 3 | System | 27-03-2024 | Active |
| Asset 3 | Security | 21-02-2024 | Active |
| Asset 3 | Application | 15-06-2023 | Active |

I'm expecting the below output:

| Name | SourceType | Date | Status |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Asset 1 | Security | 27-03-2024 | In-Active |
| Asset 1 | Application | 24-03-2024 | In-Active |
| Asset 1 | System | 27-03-2024 | In-Active |
| Asset 2 | System | 27-03-2024 | In-Active |
| Asset 2 | Security | 21-02-2024 | In-Active |
| Asset 2 | Application | 15-06-2023 | In-Active |
| Asset 3 | System | 27-03-2024 | Active |
| Asset 3 | Security | 21-02-2024 | Active |
| Asset 3 | Application | 15-06-2023 | Active |

If any one SourceType is "In-Active", the other 2 should also be updated as "In-Active".
It should be mentioned Active when all the 3 SourceTypes are Active.

I would be thankful if anyone can help me with this. Thank You:)

Answer (score 0):

I suppose it depends on whether you are grouping just on Name, or Name & Date

For just Name

```
let Source = Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="Table1"]}[Content],
#"Grouped Rows" = Table.Group(Source, {"Name"}, {{"data", each 
    let base=_,     
    Inactivecount= List.Sum(List.Transform(base[Status], each if _="In-Active" then 1 else 0))>0,
    ActiveCount= Table.RowCount(base) = List.Sum(List.Transform(base[Status], each if _="Active" then 1 else 0)),
    New = Table.AddColumn(base,"Status2", each if ActiveCount then "Active" else if Inactivecount then "In-Active" else [Status]),
    #"Removed Columns" = Table.RemoveColumns(New,{"Status"})
    in #"Removed Columns", type table }}),
#"Expanded data" = Table.ExpandTableColumn(#"Grouped Rows", "data", {"SourceType", "Date", "Status2"}, {"SourceType", "Date", "Status"})
in  #"Expanded data"
```

[image]

for Name and Date

```
let Source = Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="Table1"]}[Content],
#"Grouped Rows" = Table.Group(Source, {"Name","Date"}, {{"data", each 
    let base=_,     
    Inactivecount= List.Sum(List.Transform(base[Status], each if _="In-Active" then 1 else 0))>0,
    ActiveCount= Table.RowCount(base) = List.Sum(List.Transform(base[Status], each if _="Active" then 1 else 0)),
    New = Table.AddColumn(base,"Status2", each if ActiveCount then "Active" else if Inactivecount then "In-Active" else [Status]),
     #"Removed Columns" = Table.RemoveColumns(New,{"Status"})
    in #"Removed Columns", type table }}),
#"Expanded data" = Table.ExpandTableColumn(#"Grouped Rows", "data", {"SourceType", "Status2"}, {"SourceType", "Status"})
in  #"Expanded data"
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you correctly, I think you can just do a `Table.ReplaceValue` aggregation operation on each subgroup of `Name`

```
let

//change next line to reflect actual data source
    Source = Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="Table5"]}[Content],
    #"Changed Type" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(Source,{
        {"Name", type text}, {"SourceType", type text}, {"Date", type date}, {"Status", type text}}),

//Group by name
    #"Grouped Rows" = Table.Group(#"Changed Type", {"Name"}, {

    //If any Status is "In-Active", then replace all with "In-Active" else don't change anything
        {"Transform", (t)=> if List.MatchesAny(t[Status],each _ = "In-Active") 
            then Table.ReplaceValue(t,each [Status], "In-Active",Replacer.ReplaceValue,{"Status"})
            else t, type table[Name=text, SourceType=text, Date=date, Status=text]
        }}),
        
    #"Expanded Transform" = Table.ExpandTableColumn(#"Grouped Rows", "Transform", {"SourceType", "Date", "Status"})
in
    #"Expanded Transform"
```

[image]